# Changing the value of "id=" with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, request, onclick, document, href

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
<a id="load" href="#" class="btn load" onclick="request(this); $('#load').fadeOut(2000)">add</a>

<a href="#" id="test" onClick="alert( 'TEST!' )">here</a>

<script language="javascript">
var requests = 2;

function request(self)
{if(self.href != "#")
requests -= 1;

if(requests === 0)
document.getElementById("test").id= "nextstep";}
</script>
```

**I want id="test" to change to id="nextstep" if the requests = 0.**

Comment: Safari 4, as I tested in others as well, and this didn't work?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

Comment: You may want to look at http://webkit.org/blog/68/understanding-html-xml-and-xhtml/, as xhtml 1.0 is different than html 4. You may find html 4 to be better. For more on the setAttribute and why it may not have worked you can look at http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute

Comment: Can this be done with jQuery? As I am already using jQuery, so that might make it easier, and make it work?

Comment: I suggest looking at my answer on your other question for a completely different way of solving your problem without having to adjust the hrefs and ids -- simply adding/removing handlers based on the state of the application.

Comment: Why would you ever want to change the id value?

Comment: excellent question.  can be used to dynamically change some behaviors which a class cant.  kudos UPVOTED :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try:

```
document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('id', 'nextstep');
```

Comment: No need to use `setAttribute` (unless we are talking about XML DOM) `element.id = 'nextstep'` should be enough in this case.

Comment: I was looking for this everywhere, now I finally found it. With this I could add whatever I wanted. For example `htmlElement.setAttribute('madeUp', 'something');`. Not sure if you need to save it, but I did that. `htmlElement.save()`.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how you'd go about doing it, as long as you wrap it in script tags...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if(requests === 0){
    document.getElementById('test').id = "nextstep";
}
</script>
```

If you're trying to trigger this on the click of that anchor, then you'd use:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function changeID(){
    if(requests === 0){
        document.getElementById('test').id = "nextstep";
        alert('TEST!');
    }
}
</script>

<a href="#" id="test" onclick="changeID()">Test</a>
```

**EDIT:** Well you changed the content of your question after I posted this...

Comment: Yes, do you understand what I'm trying to do now? haha

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'setAttribute' to change the ID of anchor tag.

You've got the getElementById('test') part right, but just throw ".setAttribute('id','nextstep');"

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

> if(self.href != "#")

There's your problem. Link hrefs are canonicalised by the browser, so a link ‘#’ on page ‘http://www.example.com/’ has an href attribute of ‘http://www.example.com/#’ and does not match the condition.

Avoid using the name ‘self’, as it clashes with the name of the global object (aka ‘window’). You can avoid the clumsy passing in of ‘self’ by assigning the handler from JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('load').onclick= request;
```

instead of the `onclick` attribute, then you could use ‘this’ in request(). request() should also `return false;` to stop the link being followed (making the browser scroll to the top). Better still would be to use a `<button>` (or `<input type="button">`), because it's an action button and not a link that you could open in a new window or bookmark. (You can always use CSS to make it look less like a button.)

Don't use setAttribute() for HTML, it has problems in IE unrelated to this usage. Setting `element.id` was already fine.

But this all seems like rather a strange way of going about what you want to do in any case.